# Is there a good way in bazel to depend on a file timestamp?

Tags: bazel

I'd like to write a rule in Bazel that only considers a target to need rebuilding if a file's timestamp is before a certain amount of time ago.  For example, if I had the threshold at 6 hours, it would only rebuild the target if the file was last modified over 6 hours ago.

I will likely write this up using `genrule`, but that's clunky and will be platform-dependent, so will need per-OS implementations.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: While there are ways of doing this, I'd strongly recommend against it. One of the things that make Bazel great is it's ability to provide reproducible builds. By making your build depend on the current time it's no longer reproducible and you loose a lot of the speed and caching. Why exactly do you need to do this in first place?

Comment: @silvergasp What i was hoping to do is update a netrc file for remote archive credentials automatically. Thinking about it more, I agree this is the wrong way to go about this. It looks like https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/15013 will do what I want in bazel 6.0 by enabling credential helpers, which is a better solution—will just wait for that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question that I asked because I don't think what I was trying to do makes sense anymore.

Comment: Ah yeah, that sounds like a reasonable option. As a workaround you could make a deployment script that get's the current time stamp and updates a netrc file. i.e. using timestamps in a executable run via `bazel run //some:target` would be totally reasonable. But injecting timestamps into your build might hurt performance/correctness.

Comment: And just to be clear it's totally possible to inject a timestamp into a build. It just usually causes more headaches than it's worth. Here's an example of a bazel toolchain were timestamps have been specifically disabled for GCC. https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/blob/daf6ace7cfeacd6a83e9ff2ed659f416537b6c74/cc/private/toolchain/freebsd_cc_toolchain_config.bzl#L110-L112